# Running Pi headless with boot-up script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to run a headless Raspberry Pi, working as a voice-activated servo-motor mover. I have a Python script that does everything I need (voice and GPIO control). All I need is to get it to run my `.py` on boot. I have a Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspbian Jessie.

Things I've tried so far:

edited `/etc/rc.local` as below:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

before the `exit 0` line.

I've edited `crontab` with:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myscript.py &
```

I have also tried

```
@reboot sh /home/launcher.sh
```

where `launcher.sh` just launches the Python script.

Is there anything else I can do?

#### EDIT

I swapped the `crontab` line to look like this now:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh > /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

and my cron log is getting errors that I've never seen before, that seem to center around my mic's hardware.

```
 Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
 Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
 Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters,  sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency,  &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line:   2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/voice_pantilt.py", line 30, in <module>
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000,       input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
   stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
 self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997`
```

Note that these aren't errors when I just do:

```
 python myscript.py
```

Comment: Within the python file creates the logic of a log to know what problem causes your script to close.

Comment: Most problems like this are caused by permissions or environment variables being different from normal when running from `cron`, or as `root` in the case of `/etc/rc.local`. You could try switching to the user `pi`  to run your script maybe... `su -c 'python myscript.py' - pi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue recently and after much debugging in the end it appeared to be a problem with PyAudio being denied access to PulseAudio when run via crontab.

The way I fixed it was by prefixing the command with `export DISPLAY=:0 &&`

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
```